# How can I make this small pseudocode comply with Liskov principle?

Tags: java, solid-principles, liskov-substitution-principle, open-closed-principle

Keeping things tidy and simple, here is my initial Java pseudocode as an example:

```
public abstract class Vehicle {        
     private String owner;
     private id plate;

     public removeVehicle() {
         if (typeof(this) == Car) {this.removeCar();}
         if (typeof(this) == Truck) {this.removeTruck();}
     }
}

public class Car extends Vehicle {
     public removeCar() {
        this.removeVehicle(this);
     }
}

public class Truck extends Vehicle {
     public removeTruck() {
        this.removeVehicle(this);
     }         
}
```

From the book [Agile principles patterns and practices in C# by Robert, Micah Martin](https://www.amazon.es/s?k=agile%20principles%20patterns%20and%20practices%20in%20c&hvadid=80814136425042&hvbmt=be&hvdev=c&hvqmt=e&tag=bingamazonest-21&ref=pd_sl_8ah3fbljul_e) says that it does not comply with Liskov principle since `Vehicle`, in order to remove other vehicles types (e.g. `Motorcicle`), needs to extend code and add another `if` statement for this new type of vehicle.

I tried to follow solutions provided from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56860/what-is-an-example-of-the-liskov-substitution-principle), but most are just taken from the book I just referrenced and I'm actively trying to properly understand.

**How can I modify this pseudocode so it does comply with Liskov?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to

> "Functions that use pointers or references to base classes must be able to use objects of derived classes without knowing it."

see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID

The target of your exercise could be to define `removeVehicle` in `class Vehicle` as `abstract` and implement it in the classes which extend `Vehicle`.